# Rolling a circle around a two dimensional curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

This is a sort of funny idea I had the other day, and although I expect to get a very technical answer I am fine with any intuitive explanation.

Consider being given a function in the plane, for example $y = x^2$, or maybe even implicitly defined functions. If we were to take a circle and roll it along either side of every part of the curve defined by the equation, what is the largest circle that can do this without having to jump any gaps of the curve?

So for instance, $y = x^2$  has points at $(-1, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$, a distance of $2$ units, so obviously a circle of diameter $2$ rolling along from the right would not get down to the groove of the origin, it would skip over to the other side above somewhere and have to roll up again.

I assume this has something to do with the second derivative but I'm not sure quite how to apply it. I understand the problem is very general, so a solution to just the case $y = x^2$ would suffice for me. I am not very good at geometry admittedly, but I am open to any interesting suggestions of that form.

If there are any topological explanations for this kind of thing, such as a definition I am unfamiliar with, I would like to know about that as well.

Comment: The parabola has a _radius of curvature_ of $\frac12$ at $(0,0)$. This point has the lowest radius of curvature of the whole curve. Basically, this means that a circle of radius $\frac12$ can roll on the inside, touching every point of the parabola, but no bigger circle will be able to touch $(0,0)$ as it rolls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph The radius of curvature at a point is the reciprocal of the curvature.  Compute the minimal value of the radius of curvature, and that is the biggest circle that will work.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_%28mathematics%29

E.g. $y = x^2$, then $\kappa = |y''|/(1+(y')^2)^{3/2} = 2/(1+4x^2)^{3/2}$.  So radius of curvature is $\frac12(1+4x^2)^{3/2}$ and its minimum value is $\frac12$.

Comment: Is it clear that a circle of that radius will actually work?  I agree that it's an upper bound on what will work.  But, for a non-function counterexample consider a spiral which starts with a very large radius and VERY slowly, decreases.  Then, near the outisde, the radius of curvature is gigantic, but only a very tiny circle can fit in between the spirals.  (I should add that I do think it works in the parabola case, but I'm not sure about more general functions).

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, I think you are correct.  But I think that for any graph of the form $y = f(x)$, you won't have that problem.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes I agree with you that the curvature is not enough in general, but the answer leads me to the right sources. Perhaps there is a solution that involves solving the solution set of all tangent circles to see if there is only ever one point